# JSON: RFC8259 Escape forward slash or not?

Tags: json, standards

It seems that the RFC8259 and ECMA-404 definitions of JSON are unclear on the escaping of solidus, aka forward slash.

RFC8259 states:

> Any character may be escaped.

> All Unicode characters may be placed within the    quotation marks,
> except for the characters that MUST be escaped:    quotation mark,
> reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000    through
> U+001F).

```
char = unescaped /
          escape (
              %x22 /          ; "    quotation mark  U+0022
              %x5C /          ; \    reverse solidus U+005C
              %x2F /          ; /    solidus         U+002F
              %x62 /          ; b    backspace       U+0008
              %x66 /          ; f    form feed       U+000C
              %x6E /          ; n    line feed       U+000A
              %x72 /          ; r    carriage return U+000D
              %x74 /          ; t    tab             U+0009
              %x75 4HEXDIG )  ; uXXXX                U+XXXX

      escape = %x5C              ; \

      quotation-mark = %x22      ; "

      unescaped = %x20-21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-10FFFF
```

Here solidus is the *only* character which is mentioned in the "escape" block, which also falls in the "unescaped"  range.

Why is it mentioned so explicitly here? Should it be escaped, or should it not?

Comment: No, it does not (and generally should not) be escaped - but yeah, it's the only character that has 3 valid representations in JSON! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped theorises that it's to simplify escaping JSON embedded in `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Section 7 of RFC8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8259/) concerns strings:

> All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks, **except for the characters that MUST be escaped:
> quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000
> through U+001F).**

Since the forward slash (solidus) is not listed in the characters that MUST be escaped ("MUST" meaning "mandatory"), then the forward slash does not need to be escaped.

The next paragraph begins "Any character **may** be escaped." Here the significant word is "may" which means you are allowed to escape the character, but it is not mandatory. It is perfectly valid JSON to have `/` or `%x2F` in a JSON string literal.

The table showing the escaped and non-escaped versions of characters might have caused confusion. The conversion table does not imply you must escape those characters. Instead, the conversion table exists to describe the escaped values as part of the specification. It does not make such conversions mandatory. It is purely informational.